# Text caption overlaps with textfield in Xcode when creating new project

Tags: xcode, macos

Found same question but no answer to it thus ask again....
When I open 'New File' and choose 'Single View Application' for project template in XCode(7.3.1) of macOS(10.12.3), saw text overlaps of caption and input field as below. Could anyone help figure out how to fix it...
[image]

Comment: Have you tried delete and re-install?

Comment: Problem remains unfortunately after re-install....